Wp-admin wrongly redirecting on multisite
I have a Wordpress subdirectory multisite configured on Nginx, with Cloudflare CDN. I've set all up on Nginx and wp-config.php according to other websites I have functioning correctly with the multisite structure.
On this website the wp-admin is not opening, it "duplicates" the URL when trying to access it. Usually, it should redirect from example.com/wp-admin to example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
But on this website, is redirecting from example.com/wp-admin to example.com/wp-admin/example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
When accessing it directly through example.com/wp-login.php it works, but the dashboard opens without CSS:
Removing the multisite lines from wp-config.php it works normally.

Solved it adding an annotation to the ingress:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-admin)$ $1$2/ break;
  rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-admin/.*)$ $1$2 break;

And changing the pathtype to ImplementationSpecific

Add the below code to your wp-config.php file and observe any issues that may causes this issue and resolve them
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );


We've already tried to add the WP DEBUG code, but it shows nothing. The error showing is 404 because this URL being redirected does not exist.

install this extension from Chrome and see where is redirect : https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/redirect-path/aomidfkchockcldhbkggjokdkkebmdll?hl=en
